# MySQL Query Optimization Group By with Max

Tags: mysql, database-design, optimization, group-by

I have posted same question on at [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55347821) but I did not get any structural solution so I am trying to get answer on dba specific community.

Trying to optimise MySQL query which uses Group by with Max. Trying to get latest updated frames which were active before any past date.

**TABLE audit_frame_master**

```
CREATE TABLE `audit_frame_master` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `audit_type` enum('INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE') NOT NULL,
  `frame_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `sort_order` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `frame_type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `frame_content_type` varchar(45) DEFAULT 'default',
  `movable` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `frame_tags` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
  `frame_hint` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `size` double DEFAULT '0',
  `lastModified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deletedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `optin_algorithm` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
  `optin_menu` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `framemaster_frame_type_idx` (`frame_type`),
  KEY `fk_afm_frame_id_idx` (`frame_id`),
  KEY `afm_updatedOn_idx` (`updatedOn`),
  KEY `afm_composite_idx` (`active`,`updatedOn`,`deletedOn`),
  KEY `afm_covering_idx` (`active`,`updatedOn`,`deletedOn`,`frame_id`,`id`,`sort_order`,`createdOn`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_afm_frame_id` FOREIGN KEY (`frame_id`) REFERENCES `frame_master` (`frame_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1079822 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**TABLE audit_frame_association**

```
CREATE TABLE `audit_frame_association` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `audit_type` enum('INSERT','UPDATE') DEFAULT NULL,
  `frame_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `entity_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `entity_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `createdOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `afa_frame_id_idx` (`frame_id`),
  KEY `fk_afa_entity_id_idx` (`entity_type`),
  KEY `afa_createdOn_idx` (`createdOn`),
  KEY `afa_composite_idx` (`createdOn`,`active`,`entity_type`,`entity_id`),
  KEY `afa_covering_idx` (`createdOn`,`active`,`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`frame_id`,`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_afa_entity_type` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type`) REFERENCES `entity_type_master` (`entity_type`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_afa_frame_id` FOREIGN KEY (`frame_id`) REFERENCES `frame_master` (`frame_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=81166 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Query**

```
SELECT fm.frame_id 
FROM 
               (SELECT *,MAX(id) as id1
                              FROM audit_frame_master 
        WHERE updatedOn <='2019-03-13 10:49:29' 
        GROUP BY frame_id) fm, 
               (SELECT *,MAX(id) as id1
                              FROM audit_frame_association 
        WHERE createdOn <='2019-03-13 10:49:29' 
        AND (entity_id,entity_type) IN ((707,1)) 
        GROUP BY frame_id,entity_id,entity_type) fa 
WHERE fm.frame_id=fa.frame_id 
AND fm.active=1 
AND fm.deletedOn IS NULL 
AND fa.active=1 
GROUP BY fm.frame_id 
ORDER BY fm.sort_order = 0, fm.sort_order ASC, fm.createdOn DESC;
```

**EXPLAIN QUERY**
[image]

**Performance:**

audit_frame_master has 1M rows and thus taking more than a minute to execute single query.

Any query changes or any db schema suggestion to improve performance would be appreciated.

Comment: Before you get to performance improvements, `SELECT *,MAX(id) ... GROUP BY frame_id` and later WHERE fm.active=1 I believe will give you undeterministic results. You may have a functional dependency which may save you, I don't know your dataset to be sure, but that is dangerous. Later you have an implicit JOIN of the subqueries which makes difficult to understand what you are trying to do. I would suggest to redo your query as a simple 2-table join and then start with the optimization phase in to out (you can later do a subquery for further ordering, but secondary). Please paste the EXPLAIN.

Comment: @jynus I have added EXPLAIN statement.